# I can't understand the result about gaussian probability distribution in my text book

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

In one exercise about Probabilistic model, the book gave to me the following distribution:[gaussian function distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8eENE.png)

This is  a very complicate expression. I wanna find the marginal function in y, ok it's only apply this property:
[property to obtain marginals functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EukCb.png)

but the book has arrived in the following result:

[Result of marginal py(Y)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHEYM.png)

I can't understand how to arrive in the result above. Could someone explain to me how to arrive in this result?

Comment: So, your question is essentially, how to show: $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma^2\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}e^{-\frac12\frac{x^2-2\rho xY + Y^2}{\sigma^2}}dx =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{Y^2}{2\sigma^2}} $$  How far have you got with this?

Comment: Correction: $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma^2\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}e^{-\frac12\frac{x^2-2\rho xY + Y^2}{\sigma^2(1-\rho^2)}}dx =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{Y^2}{2\sigma^2}} $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the general result for marginal distributions applied to the joint normal pdf for (X,Y), $$p_y(Y)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma^2\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}e^{-\frac12\frac{x^2-2\rho xY + Y^2}{\sigma^2(1-\rho^2)}}dx $$
Note that $$x^2-2\rho xY + Y^2 = (x-\rho Y)^2-\rho^2 Y^2+Y^2 $$ so
$$ \frac{x^2-2\rho xY + Y^2}{\sigma^2(1-\rho^2)}=\frac{(x-\rho Y)^2}{\sigma^2(1-\rho^2)}+\frac{(1-\rho^2)Y^2}{\sigma^2(1-\rho^2)}=\left(\frac{x-\rho Y}{\sigma \sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\right)^2+\frac{Y^2}{\sigma^2}.$$
If we use the substitution $$u=\frac{x-\rho Y}{\sigma \sqrt{1-\rho^2}}$$ then the limits of the integration are unchanged and $dx$ can be replaced with $\sigma \sqrt{1-\rho^2} du.$

Also $$2\pi\sigma^2=\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma.\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma$$

So the above integration can be written: 
$$p_y(Y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}e^{-\frac12(u^2+\frac{Y^2}{\sigma^2})}\sigma \sqrt{1-\rho^2} du $$

$$p_y(Y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sigma \sqrt{1-\rho^2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}e^{-\frac12u^2}e^{-\frac12\frac{Y^2}{\sigma^2}} du $$

$$ p_y(Y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-\frac12\frac{Y^2}{\sigma^2}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac12u^2} du.$$

It is a standard result that the integral here equals 1, so $$p_y(Y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-\frac12\frac{Y^2}{\sigma^2}}$$ $$p_y(Y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{\frac{-Y^2}{2\sigma^2}}$$ as required.

Comment: Nice!   Very good explanation. Thanks so much!